# material-ui search icons is not imported

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, material-ui, material-icons

```
import React from 'react'
import {Search} from "@material-ui/icons/Search"
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
    <Search/>
    </div>
  )
}
export default App
```

export 'Search' (imported as 'Search') was not found in '@material-ui/icons/Search' (possible exports: __esModule, default)

export 'Search' (imported as 'Search') was not found in '@material-ui/icons/Search' (possible exports: __esModule, default)

search icons is not imported,but i installed material packages and it is not showing in package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct import is:

```
import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';
```

If you haven't already, you'll have to install

```
npm i @mui/icons-material
```

You can find all of the icons here: https://mui.com/material-ui/material-icons/

Comment: i installed but its not showing on my package dependency @Alexxino

Comment: If you already have installed mui-material packages, you'll have to run this command in the root folder of your react app

Comment: i installed the packages, but its not showing on my package.json no dependecy like material,but i installed both ways also@Alexxino

Comment: How did you create the react-app?

Comment: npx create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

if you look closely at your import statement

**Wrong: /!\**

```js
import { Search } from "@material-ui/icons/Search
```

you are importing a module named Search, which already has a default export.
In order to use the default export you should use

**Working:**

```js
import Search from "@material-ui/icons/Search
```

If you want to import multiple icons you should use the route `/icons`,
Then consume all the icons that you want here is how you can achieve that:

**Working:**

```js
import { Search, Mail } from "@material-ui/icons
```

To install run:

```
npm install @mui/icons-material @mui/material @emotion/styled @emotion/react
```

Comment: material-ui packages are installed but its not showing on package.json@Moussa Bistami